Using VBA to automate generation of multiple Word documents populated with data from an Excel sheet
When I run the following code, I get a 1004 error and it highlights the below. The error seems to be the path, but I do not know what the issue is.
Sub RentalFormstoWord()
 
 'Declare variables for this automation
 Dim wd As word.Application 'Word Application
 Dim wdDOC As word.Document 'Word Document
 Dim iRow As Long 'Variable to hold the starting row and loop through all records in the table
 Dim sh As Worksheet 'Worksheet variable to refer the sheet where we have stored the table
 
 'Start word and a new document
 
 Set wd = New word.Application
 
 'set worksheet where table is available
 
 Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory Master Doc")
 
 iRow = 2 'initialize iRow with 2 as our data is starting from row number 2 in table
 
 Do While sh.Range("A" & iRow).Value <> ""
 
    'opening the word template
    
    Set wdDOC = wd.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Band_Rental_Agreement.dotx")
    wd.Visible = False

I've tried naming the path "\Band Rental Agreement.dotx", I've copied and pasted the doc title, I've used underscores instead of the spaces, and I've copied the path itself.

Just to be sure, it highlights the Set wdDoc line? What is the value of  ThisWorkbook.Path ? Could the .dotx be open already in another instance of Word (can happen rather easily when testing!). (Also, not part of your question, but if you are trying to create a new document based on the .dotx then you need wd.Document.Add instead of wd.Documents.Open)
